# Rails model association - Help me fix this issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am creating a simple app for practice and I'm having a problem with it. I have a 3 models. user model a product model and a photo model. A user has_many products and products has_many photos. So far so good but I get this error when I try to submit a new product.

> NoMethodError in ProductsController#create
>
> undefined method `photo' for #(Product:0xb69a6f8)

**products controller**

```
def new
  @product = Product.new
  @photo   = Photo.new
end

def create
    @photo = current_user.photos.build(params[:photo])  
    @product = current_user.products.build(params[:product])

  if @product.save
     render "show", :notice => "Sale created!"
  else
     render "new", :notice => "Somehting went wrong!"
  end
end
```

**product model**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :description, :name

 belongs_to :user
 has_many :photos, dependent: :destroy

 validates :user_id,      presence: true
 validates :photo,        presence: true
end
```

**photo model**

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
    validates_attachment :image, presence: true,
                            content_type: { content_type: ['image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png', 'image/gif'] },
                            size: { less_than: 5.megabytes }
    has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "320x240>"}

end
```

**user model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation
  has_secure_password

  has_many :products, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :photos, :through => :products

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5 }
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5 }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true


end
```

**my super simple new product view**

```
= form_for @product do |f|
  %p
    = f.label :name
    = f.text_field :name
  %p
    = f.label :description
    = f.text_field :description

  %p.button
    = f.submit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have linked the tables but didn't have a setter getter for photo there. Hope it helps!!!

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :description, :name, :photo

 belongs_to :user
 has_many :photos, dependent: :destroy

 validates :user_id,      presence: true
 validates :photo,        presence: true
end
```

If `:photo` variable is not there in Product model then you have to create a column for photo in Products db table by using the migration, for that you should be doing something like this:

`$ rails g migration AddPhotoToProducts photo:string`

Comment: wouldnt it be rails g migration AddPhotoToProducts photo:string  replacing  migrate with migration and making product plural?

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty clear: You're invoking `.photo` on a `Product`, however, your `Product` has many `photos`;  note the 's'. There is no `.photo` on a given product. You need to use `product.photos`, which is an array-like object of zero or more photos.